How to proper "install" the python wrapper of Indy-vdr
I'm following the instructions of Indy-vdr to use its python wrapper. It says:

The Python wrapper is located in wrappers/python/indy_vdr. In order
for the wrapper to locate the shared library, the latter may be placed
in a system shared library directory like /usr/local/lib.

I added the contents of the folder wrapper/python/ in the folder /usr/local/ib/python3.8/dist-packages, which is in my system patch:
python3.8 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
['', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

And the files are:
ubuntu@indy1:/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages$ ls
demo  indy_vdr  readme.md  setup.cfg  setup.py

When I try to run the demo, or a simple code to get its version I get an error that indy_vdr was not found. But the weird part is that I can do import indy_vdr, and it imports correctly. but I can't do anything else:
Demo:
ubuntu@indy1:~/indy-vdr/wrappers$ python3 -m demo.test
Library not loaded from python package
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 192, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/demo/test.py", line 246, in <module>
    log("indy-vdr version:", version())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/indy_vdr/bindings.py", line 449, in version
    lib = get_library()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/indy_vdr/bindings.py", line 88, in get_library
    LIB = _load_library("indy_vdr")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/indy_vdr/bindings.py", line 116, in _load_library
    raise VdrError(VdrErrorCode.WRAPPER, f"Error loading library: {lib_name}")
indy_vdr.error.VdrError: Error loading library: indy_vdr

Simple command:
ubuntu@indy1:~/indy-vdr/wrappers$ python3 -c "import indy_vdr; print(indy_vdr.version())"
Library not loaded from python package
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/indy_vdr/bindings.py", line 449, in version
    lib = get_library()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/indy_vdr/bindings.py", line 88, in get_library
    LIB = _load_library("indy_vdr")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/indy_vdr/bindings.py", line 116, in _load_library
    raise VdrError(VdrErrorCode.WRAPPER, f"Error loading library: {lib_name}")
indy_vdr.error.VdrError: Error loading library: indy_vdr

